# Form that sends data to an admin panel and can export it

Tags: database, forms

Is there a way to have a form submit data to a admin control panel where the data is stored and can be rectified there? Could it also be able to export the data as excel for example?

Comment: If I understand you better ... you want to have a form that submits data ... but you want to see the results of the data in a CSV or somewhere that doesn't require logging into WordPress?

Comment: @Damien, preferably in stand alone user admin panel. I would in fact have to convert a lot of Excel sheets already in existance into a database to be stored in the database/admin panel, where it could then be accessible and exported to formats like excel, word, etc. But from then on I would have to have a form to be filled with the user's details and stored in the database as well.

Comment: you say you want an Admin Panel BUT you don't want the user to login to WordPress Admin - but you 'cant' really do that. Why not create a WordPress user that only has login access and to see the form data? that is easy to do with a plugin like User Role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 very popular form plugins

1. [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) - extremely customisable and saves all data to your database (Commercial)
2. [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) - also saves everything to your database and easy to use (Free)

Both send the data to the Admin panel so you can review inside WordPress.

I know that Gravity Forms has an option to EXPORT the form entries as a CSV file.

**Review Form Submissions without logging in**
Both can send email notifications to your email address so you can see what has been submitted without logging into WordPress.

The other way to see all the form submissions without logging in is to open your SQL database and view the data there. Then you can save the table as a CSV.

Comment: I mean a special admin panel easy to use that is not inside Wordpress menu (if that would be even possible). How can I gain 15 reputation to rep someone btw

Comment: there are lots of ways to earn rep ... 1. Complete your profile.  2. try reading all the FAQ's at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq youll get a badge for that and 3. check your priveldges. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges  and  be careful to stop asking questions that are getting you negative rep.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [admin panel class](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/my-options-panel) which is create admin panel pages for you with ease and has **Import Export features**.

And Available fields are:

- Input
- Textarea
- Radio button
- Checkbox
- Select Dropdown
- File Upload
- Image Upload
- WYSIWYG editor
- Date Picker
- Time Picker
- Color Picker
- Taxonomy List Dropdwon or checkboxes
- Post list Dropdown or checkboxes
- WordPress User Roles Dropdown or checkboxes
- Syntax Highlighted Code Editor (PHP, CSS, HTML, JAVASCRIPT)
- Typography Field (set of size, color, face, family fields)
- Sortable Drag & Drop
- Repeater Field which can be set as sortable
- Conditional Field block

Comment: So that creates admin panel pages? How would they be accessible to the user? Would that be inside wordpress as well?

Comment: you set the needed capability when you create the page/panel and its for using inside the WordPress admin area.